# How to recode values in a variable in a data frame in R

Tags: r, variables, recode

I have a datatable, dataframe which has a variable:
grade_c:Factor w/8 Level.
0, A, B, C, D, E, F, NA

And I want to change the variables to ->

0-> NA

A-> 1

B-> 2

C-> 3

...

F-> 6

I saw that I can recode variables with this code:

```
NonTestMergeV$grade_c[NonTestMergeV$grade_c=="A"] <- 1
```

But when I try it I get this warning. And nothing changes...

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, NonTestMergeV$grade_c ==
>   "A", value = c(NA,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

Any help on how to get the desired result would be helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: change them to characters first by doing `NonTestMergeV$grade_c <- as.character(NonTestMergeV$grade_c)` and then use any of the methods in the link.

Comment: @RonakShah I dont understand the links answers. This doesnt answer my question.

Comment: @RonakShah What does dictionary has to do with my numeric values?

Comment: did you convert `grade_c` column to character as mentioned above ?

Comment: Yes. Still dont get how to change them...

Comment: do `map = setNames(c(NA, 1:5), c(0,LETTERS[1:5]))` and then `NonTestMergeV$grade_c <- map[NonTestMergeV$grade_c]`